AttributeError: module 'gspread.auth' has no attribute 'console_flow'
I am trying to write an application that will run on a remote server and use the console flow (open link to authenticate on their local machine, then copy/paste code into console). However, running the following snippet provided in the documentation:
import gspread 
gc = gspread.oauth(flow=gspread.auth.console_flow)

yields the following error:
AttributeError: module 'gspread.auth' has no attribute 'console_flow' 
Indeed, the current version of gspread (6.1.0) does not define a "console_flow" text. Is there a quick workaround while I submit a bug request?

The console flow has been disabled by Google for new clients as of February 28, 2022.
https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html?m=1#disallowed-oob

If your app is using the OOB method you need to migrate to another
method which is more secure by default.

